# Projecting a Non Negative Vector onto the Simplex

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given an elementwise nonnegative vector $y$, I'd like to find the projection of $y$ onto the simplex $S: \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) ~|~ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1, x_i \geq 0 \mbox{ for all } i \}$.

Is there a closed form expression for this? If not, I need to write a computer program which will compute this projection; is there something simple I could do to compute this?

Simplicity is more important to me than running time; I don't want to spend a long time coding this. I do realize this is a convex optimization problem and could be solved by using various optimization solvers, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Do you mean the projection from the origin?  If so, the answer is simply $y/s$, where $s$ is the sum of the coordinates of $y$.

Comment: @Jim Belk - I meant "projection" to mean the map which sends $y$ to the closest point to it in $S$. Sadly, this does not turn out to equal $y/s$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221546/

Comment: [Who were you robinson? What did you see?](http://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: Related with simpler derivation - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933485.

Comment: User @sangwoongyoon helpfully provided some numpy code they had write to solve this problem. Their answer was unfortunately deleted by moderators, but here's a link to the code: https://github.com/swyoon/projsplx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the article [Projection Onto A Simplex](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.6081) by Yunmei Chen and Xiaojing Ye (the code from which is [available here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30332)), or look at any book on Convex Opimization. The "closed formula" involves sorting, and you can find it using Lagrange multipliers (the version for inequality constraints).

Comment: This article is not available.

Comment: [Found.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.6081)

Comment: There is even a [Matlab code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30332). It is unfortunately not extensively vectorized, but it is simple to do so.