# Projection onto the positive subset of a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-programming

I am wondering if there is a closed form solution for the projection of a point $x_0$ onto the subset of a hyperplane $Ax=b$ in the positive orthnat, that is $x\geq0$?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/46173) concerns the same problem (for the standard simplex), from the algorithmic point of view. I think any answer is going to be an _algorithm_ rather than a _formula_.