# A light solution of a quadratic programming problem

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming

I have a simple and light quadratic programming problem that I need to solve, as following: 
    \begin{align}
 & \underset{x}{\arg\min}
 & & \dfrac{1}{2}x^T x-z^T x\\
 & \text{subject to} 
 & & \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1,\\
 & & & x_i\geq 0\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\},\\
        & & & x=\left[x_1,\ldots,x_n\right]^T, z=\left[z_1,\ldots,z_n\right]^T.
 \end{align}

where $z$ is a constant vector.
I know there are methods like barrier method or interior-point method that can be used to solve such a problem, but I feel like this problem probably does not require a complicated method like those?

Is there any light solution that I could use to solve such a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is $z$ a variable? Without any restrictions? Also $x>0$ is a difficult concept in optimization ($x\ge0$ is more digestable).

Comment: yes, `z` is a vector without any restrictions. Yes it should be `x>=0`. Sorry about this. @ErwinKalvelagen

Comment: Looks like an unbounded problem to me. Actually I think $z$ is not a variable but a constant.

Comment: The qp algorithm of Goldfarb and Idnani is widely used (e.g. in R `quadprog`).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Yes it is a constant vector. Sorry that I was not clear before.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks, but my goal is to implement that quadratic programming method. I only need a light solution that is enough to solve the above problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following property:
$$
\frac{1}{2} x^T x - z^T x 
= \frac{1}{2}(x^T x - 2 z^T x)
= \frac{1}{2}||x - z||_2^2 - \frac{1}{2}z^T z
= \frac{1}{2}||x - z||_2^2 + CONST
$$
Hence, your problem is equivalent to:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \operatorname*{argmin}_x &\quad \frac{1}{2} ||x - z||^2 \\
    \text{subject to} &\quad \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1 \\
                      &\quad x \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$

This the well known problem of projecting $z$ onto the unit simplex, and can be solved in $O(n \log n)$ time. You can google it, or look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/projecting-a-nonnegative-vector-onto-the-simplex).

Comment: Hum... you can project onto a simplex in linear time. There are methods due to Duchi et al. (a randomized algo, so $\mathcal O(n)$ complexity is in an ergodic sense), Condat et al. (deterministic, but complicated), etc.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to derive a $O(n)$ solution during the weekend. I will verify it and see if it's correct and worth posted here.

Comment: @dohmatob Thanks. I will check their methods.